# Searching list values in another list

Tags: c#

I'm trying to perform a search on lists using other list values.

For example, I have list A with a specific set of values (1,2,3,4,5). I have another list (list B) of values (6,7,8,9,0)

I have a 3rd list (list C) with a set of values (1,3,4)

I'd like to be able to have my code use list C's values to return a matching list based on all the values in the list.

In other words, the code would return list A because values 1, 3 and 4 are all contained in that list.

If List C were to contain 1,3,4 and 7, no lists would be returned

I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LINQ's [Intersect](http://dotnetpattern.com/linq-intersect-operator) method to find the elements shared between `a` (or `b`) and `c`, and then make sure the counts are the same.

```
if (a.Intersect(c).Count() == c.Count())
    Console.WriteLine("Everything in c is in a.")
```

Comment: Used this solution. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of numbers and duplicates are not important then this code will work:

```
 var listA = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
 var listB = new List<int> { 5, 4, 6, 7 };
 var listC = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
 if (listC.Except(listA).Count() == 0)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("List A contains all numbers from list C");
 }
 if (listC.Except(listB).Count() == 0)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("List B contains all numbers from list C");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

*...a matching list based on all the values....*

There is an IEnumerable that does exactly what you have said
[Enumerable.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_All__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)

```
bool allForA = listC.All(c => listA.Contains(c));
if(allForA)
   return listA;
....
```

And, I am not sure, but probably is also the better option in terms of performance because I suppose that if an element is not found the enumeration will stop and returns false without the need to enumerate all the list's elements

**EDIT**: Out of curiosity I have tested the All approach against the Intersect one and I can confirm now that All is at least three times faster than the Intersect.
(Of course I am talking about milliseconds on a 1 million loop, so it is hardly something to worry about but nevertheless I was curious)

This is the example to run inside LinqPad (tell me if something is wrong)

```
void Main()
{
    List<int> listA = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
    List<int> listB = new List<int> {6,7,8,9,0};
    List<int> listC = new List<int> {1,3,4};

    int z = 0;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for(int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++)
        if (listB.Intersect(listC).Count() == listC.Count())
            z++;
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("INTERSECT => B");

    z = 0;
    sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++)
        if(listC.All(c => listB.Contains(c)))
            z++;
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("ALL => B");

    sw.Start();
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++)
        if (listA.Intersect(listC).Count() == listC.Count())
            z++;
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("INTERSECT => A");

    z = 0;
    sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++)
        if (listC.All(c => listA.Contains(c)))
            z++;
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("ALL => A");

}
```